# Je peux, puis-je ? Si je puis dire

Tags: conjugaison, verbes

Le verbe *pouvoir* a deux formes pour la première personne du singulier à l'indicatif présent : *je peux* et *je puis*.

Lorsque le verbe est avant le sujet (notamment dans une tournue interrogative), on utilise toujours *puis*. « Que puis-je faire pour vous ? » Sinon, la forme *puis* m'a l'air plus soutenue que *peux*. « Si je puis me permettre, je peux le faire, je ne peux pas rester à ne rien faire. »

Y a-t-il d'autres verbes en français qui ont ainsi deux formes conjuguées pour la même personne au même temps, qui se distinguent grammaticalement ?

(Il y a bien deux conjugaisons pour le verbe *asseoir*, mais sans distinction d'usage.)

Comment: Je ne me prononce pas sur les questions de pouvoir.

Comment: Il me vient à l'esprit que les verbes du premier groupe ont une forme différente lorsqu'ils précèdent le sujet : *lalala, chanté-je*. Est-ce le même phénomène ? Je n'ai pas l'impression : le `é` est une simple inflection, et utilisée exclusivement avant `je`, alors qu'on trouve aussi *je puis*.

Answer (score 7):

Parcourant la section sur les verbes irréguliers chez Grevisse, je ne vois rien d'aussi clair que pour *pouvoir*.

- *Vouloir* a deux formes à l'impératif (*voulez* et *veuillez*) et certains réservent la seconde au rôle de semi-auxiliaire de politesse, mais trouver des contre-exemples est aisé.
- On peut considérer que le verbe *aller* a deux formes pour certains temps, dont une empruntée au verbe *être*. Certains font une nuance, la forme provenant du verbe *être* impliquant un retour. Il en va de même pour d'autres verbes qui ont deux conjugaisons au moins à certains temps (*faillir*, *saillir*, *résoudre*) pour lesquels certains réservent certaines formes à certains sens, mais ce ne sont pas des usages universels. Et ce n'est pas une distinction grammaticale.

Comment: Pour *faillir* et *saillir*, tu penses à quel temps ? Pour *résoudre*, je suppose que tu penses au participe passé (*résolu* ou *résous*), il y a aussi *béni* ou *bénit* qui est dans le même cas, mais ce sont des différences de sens et non de grammaire. Pour *vouloir*, peux-tu donner un exemple de *veux* ou *voulez* à l'impératif ?

Comment: Tout le deuxième point concerne des différences de sens. _Faillir_ a des formes comme _il faut_ (_falloir_ et _faillir_ ont la même origine) aussi bien qu'une conjugaison calquée sur _finir_ que certains n'emploient que dans le sens _faire faillite_.  Pour vouloir, Grevisse cite _Faites un effort, voulez seulement_.

Comment: Pour *falloir* et *faillir*, ce sont des verbes complètement distincts (quelle que soit leur étymologie), non ? Merci pour l'exemple pour *voulez* à l'impératif.

Comment: Pour certains (dont Bescherelle dans mon édition mais c'est pas noté [ici](http://bescherelle.leconjugueur.com/frconjugue.php?verbe=faillir)) _faillir_ se conjugue _je faux_, _tu faux_... dans le sens « manquer à » et comme _finir_ dans le sens « faire faillite ».

Answer (score 2):

Pour répondre partiellement à la question (ie. sans réelle distinction d'usage), il y a effectivement d'autres dualités, comme je balaie ou je balaye. Comme disait (paraît-il) [Dominique Bouhours](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominique_Bouhours) : « Je vais ou je vas mourir, l'un et l'autre se dit ou se disent ».

Comment: Tu ne réponds pas du tout à la question, là. *Balaie/balaye*, c'est comme *assois/assieds*, ce n'est jamais dicté par la grammaire.

Comment: Je réponds partiellement, à la première partie de la question : « Y a-t-il d'autres verbes en français qui ont ainsi deux formes conjuguées pour la même personne au même temps ». Disons que c'est pour référence pour ceux qui découvrent les joies du français... J'ai hésité à mettre ça en commentaire, vu que ce n'est effectivement pas une réponse directe.