# Il s'assoit, il s'assied…

Tags: étymologie, conjugaison

La [question de Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/je-peux-puis-je-si-je-puis-dire) sur le verbe *pouvoir* m'amène à me demander quand les deux conjugaisons différentes du verbe *asseoir* se sont formées, et pourquoi coexistent-elles ?

J'ai tenté de lire les notes du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/asseoir) sur la question, mais il y est dit tout et son contraire : que *j'assois* est jugé vulgaire par certains grammairiens, mais « surtout usitée dans le style noble » par le Larousse 19<sup>e</sup>. Même bien assis (pourquoi pas *assoyé* ?) sur mon séant, j'en ai la tête qui tourne. Une âme charitable a-t-elle une ou deux références plus claires sur la question ?

Comment: J'hésite à corriger _une âme charitable a-t-il_ en _une âme charitable a-t-elle_ des fois que ce serait une figure de style volontaire.

Comment: @Joubarc ne jamais expliquer par l'originalité du style de l'auteur ce qui peut l'être par une faute d'orthographe ou de frappe

Comment: Quand l'auteur en question est modérateur, je préfère ne pas prendre de risque.

Comment: @Joubarc ça fait un peu « permission d'éditer, mon adjudant ? » — je donne donc ici permission permanente d'éditer mes posts pour me faire apparaître plus intelligent, fort et musclé que je ne le suis en réalité. Je ne me vexerai pas, et au pire, je ferai un *rollback* (terme qui n'est pas encore dans notre glossaire bilingue !).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grevisse...

> Les jugements portés sur les deux séries diffèrent d'une grammaire (ou d'un dictionnaire) à l'autre. Il y a des préférences régionales.

et sur l'histoire

> L'indic. prés. se *seoir* (lat. *sedere*) était en anc. fr. *sié*, *siez* ou *siés*, *siet*, *seons*, *seez*, *sieent*. Le singulier se continue dans *assieds*, *assied* (où on a introduit un *d* par imitation du latin). [...]
>
> Les formes en *-oi-*, *-oy-* sont dues à l'influence de l'infinitif. Elles ne sont pas récentes [citations de Rabelais, Molière,...] mais les grammairiens les signalent rarement avant le XVIII<sup>e</sup> s. — L'Acad. ne les mentionne que depuis 1835 (« quelquefois »).