# Kindly requesting a guide to the verb "Asseoir"

Tags: verbes, conjugaison

I was going through all the irregular verbs, learning their conjugations, and I got to this one and completely blanched. Now I recall that they always brushed aside questions about this verb back in high school.

Can someone kindly explain when to use the different forms of the verb, and any other peculiarities there may be?

Comment: See also: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9817/in-what-sense-is-the-second-set-of-asseoir-conjugations-more-polite, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/il-sassoit-il-sassied

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1) There are two different spellings**: *asseoir* (traditional, much more common, the one I prefer and the one I use for this answer), and *assoir* (1990 modernized grammar, typical of some official texts, but still less common).

**2) There are two strictly equivalent, fully correct conjugation forms** to *asseoir* (to make or help someone / something sit down) or *s'asseoir* (to sit down, much more common). You can use both of them, independently of the chosen (old or modernized) spelling which only applies to the infinitive.

**The first**, and less usual form is (for *s'asseoir*):

- Je m'assois
- Tu t'assois
- Il/elle s'assoit
- Nous nous assoyons
- Vous vous assoyez
- Ils/elles s'assoient

It is similar to other stem-changing verbs like *employer* or *nettoyer* (1st conjugation group), so **this conjugation is the one of a 1st group verb**, except for the infinitive (that's why it belongs to the 3rd group).

This form is very common when used with the first, second or third person singular, and the third person plural probably because of the similarity to the infinitive. *However, the first and second plural forms are uncommon*. I can't give any scientific reason for this, but it sounds like Old French, and looks  like a very common grammatical mistake made by little children for 3rd group verbs.

**The second form**, considered more common, and by some more polite, would be:

- Je m'assieds
- Tu t'assieds
- Il/elle s'assied
- Nous nous asseyons
- Vous vous asseyez
- Ils/elles s'asseyent

This is a "pure" 3rd group irregular conjugation, more [here](http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-franzosisch-verb-asseoir.html)

**3) Practical examples, meanings, and Common mistakes:**

Examples :

- My old middle school teacher, telling his class to sit down: *"Assoyez vous!"* (Could someone give me a proper, context adapted English translation?)
- What I would recommend: *"Quand je m'assieds dans un bar, j'aime être servi rapidement"* or *"Je m'asseois toujours à cette table, c'est ma préférée"*.
- Most French people will use either one of the two forms (there could be regional differences), or, when using the first one, **will almost certainly switch to the second form to avoid using 
  *nous nous assoyons* or *vous vous assoyez*** . Example: *"Je m'assois sur la chaise. Si vous vous asseyez sur le canapé, ne mettez pas vos pieds dessus!"*

Mistakes:

- *Je m'assis / Tu t'assis / Il s'assit* is often mistaken (especially among teenagers) for the present form *Je m'assieds* / *m'assois*. However, this is the "Past Simple" (I sat down). It is a common mistake among French / French-speaking people, but it is an ugly mistake.

Meanings, similar verbs :

- *Asseoir*: to make someone sit down, or to help someone "stand his ground" in an argument. *Il a assis sa position avec des arguments solides* / *Avec l'apparition de l'iPhone 2000, la companie "Pomme" a assis sa position sur le marché du téléphone portable* or *J'ai assis le bébé sur la chaise pour le repas*.
- *s'asseoir sur quelque chose*: to (intentionally) ignore or put away something (usually an argument, an opinion, a law): *Il s'est assis sur le règlement et a fait ce qu'il voulait*. You can imagine the guy in my example putting the rules under his bottom. This is not familiar, but using this construction means you clearly insist on the intention not to take the object (here the rules) into account.

Comment: IS APPLE ACTUALLY CALLED POMME IN FRANCE???

Comment: Why didn't you answer sooner? you would have had the bounty.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Companies names are not translated, though nicknames may sometimes be used. I've seen “*la compagnie à la pomme*” a few times.

Comment: I wrote "pomme" to avoid naming the company... of course it's called apple...

Comment: What a shame, I would have died laughing. (Late response, I know.)

Comment: Also, could someone elaborate on what Yves means by the second set of conjugations being occasionally considered "more polite"? I might make a new question for this.

Comment: Also, hmm, you said "You can use both of them, independently of the chosen (old or modernized) spelling which only applies to the infinitive."....but then you separately wrote *je m'assois* and *je m'asseois* in two different places.

Comment: In the 3rd paragraph, you wrote "Je m'asseois", exhibiting the optional "e" from the infinitive form. However you did not mention the possibility of includig that letter e in the two conjugated forms you listed. Was that a mistake of yours or can you actually use any of the three forms : je m'assieds, je m'assois and je m'asseois ?

Answer (score 5):

Choose one form and keep to it. You may try to guess someone origin by the form he uses, but I doubt anybody will pay attention to what a non-native speaker is using.

---

Grevisse, *le bon usage*, douzième édition,

> Les jugements portés sur les deux séries diffèrent d'une grammaire (ou d'un dictionnaire) à l'autre. Il y a des préférences régionales : les formes en -oi-, -oy- sont peu usitées en Belgique ; par contre à Paris le langage populaire ignore *assieds*, *assiérai*, etc.
>
> Dans langue écrite, *assied*, *asseyent*, *assiérai*, etc. sont plus fréquents. [...]
>
> Les formes en -oi- l'emportent au figuré [...]
>
> Les forme en -oy- sont évitées dans la langue écrite. [...]
>
> Hist. L'indic. prés de *seoir* (lat. *seddere*) était en anc. fr. *sié*, *siez* ou *siés*, *siet*, *seons*, *seez*, *sient*.  Le singulier continue dans *assieds*, *assied* (où on a introduit un *d* par imitation du latin). Un yod a été inséré pour supprimer l'hiatus dans *asseyons*, *asseyez*, ainsi que dans *asseyait*, *asseyant* ; d'où par analogie, *asseyent* à l'indic. prés. et les diverses formes en -ey- du subj. prés. et du futur. On trouve même *je m'asseye* à l'ind. prés. chez J.J. Rousseau.
>
> Les formes en -oi-, -oy-, sont dues à l'influence de l'infinitif. Elles ne sont pas récentes [citation chez Rabelai et d'autres]. L'Acad. ne les mentionne que depuis 1835 (« quelquefois »).
>
> [...]
>
> Le verbe a connu au cours de son histoire d'autres formes encore. Notons le radical en -i- à l'indicatif. [...] Le franç. populaire de Paris et de diverses régions emploie encore : °*Je m'assis*, °*Assis-toi*, etc.

Comment: Les abrév. c'est vraim. insup.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, si les fautes d'orthographe sont de mon cru, les abréviations sont d'origine.

Comment: Je dois être vieux alors: moi j'aurais dit "je m'assis" au présent...

Comment: @AlexisWilke, Ma compréhension est que c'est une forme qui n'existe plus que régionalement, être d'une de ces régions n'est pas nécessairement être vieux.

Answer (score 4):

*Asseoir* is indeed a peculiar verb.

First, it has two forms (e.g. you can say *j'asseois* et *j'assieds* for the present tense). Both of them are accepted, but the 2nd one is considered nicer.

The verb is generally used in its reflexive form. Meaning the verb object represents the subject.

> J'assieds le bébé sur sa chaise.  (*I sit the baby on her chair*)
>   Je m'assieds. [ *m'* is me ] (*I sit*)

Then, one can hardly guess the conjugation from the infinitive verb…
This is a 3rd group verb.
(See [the details](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/asseoir.html) with the two forms.)

Comment: "J'assieds les élèves" me choque un peu : "je demande aux élèves de s'asseoir" ou "j'assieds un bébé sur sa chaise". [S']asseoir est un geste, à moins de prendre les élèves un par un, je ne peux les asseoir tous. Les usage du verbe : http://francois.gannaz.free.fr/Littre/xmlittre.php?requete=asseoir&submit=Rechercher .

Comment: Dont acte. L'exemple a changé pour une phrase plus courante. Mais en langage populaire on entend *J'assieds les élèves et j'arrive* par exemple qui connote une certaine autorité sur *les élèves* (qui n'est pas explicite).