# In what sense is the second set of "asseoir" conjugations more polite?

Tags: verbes, oral

In response to [a prior question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/kindly-requesting-a-guide-to-the-verb-asseoir) I asked, the following was mentioned:

> The second form, considered more common, and by some more polite, would be:
>
> Je m'assieds
>   Tu t'assieds
>   Il/elle s'assied
>   Nous nous asseyons
>   Vous vous asseyez
>   Ils/elles s'asseyent

In what sense is it "more polite"? Could someone make an analogy to something comparable in English, maybe?

Comment: Could you precise in which way http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4614/176 (especially the "Les jugements portés sur les deux séries diffèrent d'une grammaire (ou d'un dictionnaire) à l'autre") doesn't answer your question?

Comment: I think *préciser* is best translated by *clarify*.... *precise* n'est pas un verbe en anglais. Mais en réponse (ça se dit?), je me demande la manière de cette politesse susdite.

Comment: See also: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/kindly-requesting-a-guide-to-the-verb-asseoir, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/il-sassoit-il-sassied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En réalité, le verbe "asseoir", ou "assoir" (variante orthographique autorisée par réforme) se conjugue de manière tout à fait correcte des DEUX manières citées dans votre conversation. Strictement.
Il s'agit simplement de deux formes variantes l'une de l'autre.
Cependant et de manière générale, les formes en ie et ey sont préférables aux autres formes moins distinguées (oi et oy).
Dans la pratique, je constate depuis mon enfance que l'usage le plus naturel (naturel, pas familier) et d'utiliser la forme en "oi" au singulier et la forme en "ie" au pluriel :

- je m'assois
- tu t'assois
- il s'assoit
- nous nous asseyons
- vous vous asseyez
- ils s'asseyent

plutôt que l'inverse :

- je m'assieds
- tu t'assieds
- il s'assied
- nous nous assoyons
- vous vous assoyez
- ils s'assoient

D'expérience, voici les connotations que l'on pourrait éventuellement noter pour chacun des emplois :

- je m'assieds (presque pompeux)
- tu t'assieds (presque pompeux)
- il s'assied (presque pompeux)
- nous nous asseyons (très naturel)
- vous vous asseyez (très naturel)
- ils s'asseyent (un petit peu moins naturel)
- je m'assois (très naturel)
- tu t'assois (très naturel)
- il s'assoit (très naturel)
- nous nous assoyons (moins élégant)
- vous vous assoyez (moins élégant)
- ils s'assoient (possède le défaut de ne pas être phonétiquement distinguable de "il s'assoit". Cependant, son usage reste assez répandu.)

Pour la dernière personne du pluriel, la "règle du naturel" est moins prédominante, c'est plutôt le contexte qui fixe le choix de la forme a employer - c'est en tout cas le cas pour moi.

Si le contexte assure à l'auditeur que le sujet est bien "ils", et non "il", j'aurai tendance à employer "ils s'assoient", alors que dans un cas plus ambiguë, je choisirais probablement "ils s'asseyent".

J'espère vous avoir d'avantage éclairé qu'embrouillé.

Answer (score 2):

**Short english version** :

Both ways are considered correct. The form you're quoting (*je m'assieds* ...) is not more polite, it's just the one that sounds slightly more old-fashioned and therefore more formal. Some people are confusing politeness and language correctness, which are two different things.

---

Comme précisé par 'Un francophone' en commentaire de la question, il y a déjà des éléments très utiles dans [une question précédente](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/kindly-requesting-a-guide-to-the-verb-asseoir/), mais on peut préciser que :

La variante *je m'assois* (+ ses dérivés) a tendance à prendre le pas sur sa concurrente (*je m'assieds* et ses dérivés). Quand j'ai fait mes études il y a une vingtaine d'années, il était considéré un peu plus correct d'utiliser *je m'assieds*, notamment dans les contextes les plus 'sérieux', bien que la première soit également tolérée, y compris à l'écrit. Cela dit, il est probable que ces considérations varient également en fonction de la zone géographique et du milieu social. Le reste s'explique par l'amalgame entre correction de langage et politesse, choses pourtant distinctes mais que certains confondent.

Comment: Ça me semble faux pour « nous nous assoyons, vous vous assoyez » qui tendent à disparaître.

Comment: Pareil pour « assois-toi », jamais entendu.

Comment: @Edouard c'est difficile à dire, notamment parce que les cas d'utilisation (de ces formes ainsi que de leurs homologues *nous nous asseyons, vous vous asseyez*) sont rares tels quels. Dans un cadre informel/courant, on aura presque toujours autre chose, comme *On se met assis*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tu as raison, la forme impérative fait exception, même à l'époque je n'ai jamais utilisé ni entendu cette forme, toujours *assieds-toi / asseyez-vous*.

Answer (score 1):

Ma grand-mère, qui vivait en Belgique, me disait "Assois-toi et reste tranquille !".

Je lui ai demandé pourquoi ma mère, qui vivait en Suisse, me disait d’habitude "Assieds-toi", elle m'a répondu "Tiens-toi assis maintenant ! Je t'expliquerai plus tard…".

Je n'ai jamais reçu l'explication promise, alors j’ai essayé diverses variantes à divers moments pour finalement conclure que l’on disait Asseoir lorsqu’on était en colère et Assir au autres moments.

Il m’a fallu du temps pour comprendre qu’Assir n’existait pas et que ma théorie sur l’état d’âme du locuteur n’était pas valide.