# Je puis, je peux, et la poésie

Tags: oral, poésie

Tout le monde [connaît](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/%C2%AB_Puisque_j%E2%80%99ai_mis_ma_l%C3%A8vre_%C3%A0_ta_coupe_encor_pleine_%C2%BB) :

> Je puis maintenant dire aux rapides années :
>   — Passez ! Passez toujours ! je n'ai plus à vieillir ;

Je m'interroge sur le *puis*. Pourquoi Victor Hugo n'a-t-il pas mis *peux* ?

Je comprends intuitivement que concernant la sonorité, *puis* est mieux que *peux*, comme si l'on mettait une sorte de dièse. Et concernant le sens, que *puis* introduit une forme de retrait par rapport à *peux*.

Mais, si vous confirmez, pourriez-vous m'expliquer cela de façon mieux argumentée ?

J'ai lu le TLF, évidemment, sur [pouvoir](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/pouvoir). Je n'ai rien vu de spécifique, sauf que *puis* serait une forme vieillie, mais que ça veut dire exactement la même chose que *peux*. Cela reste pour des raisons pratiques, parce que c'est mieux de dire *puis-je* que *peux-je*. Donc j'aurais tort sur le sens, mais ça me laisse sur ma faim pour ce qui concerne la sonorité poétique de ce vers.

Et j'ai vu également la question [*Je peux, puis-je ? Si je puis dire*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/je-peux-puis-je-si-je-puis-dire), mais je m'intéresse au cas particulier de *puis* et de ce vers.

Comment: Il faut utiliser `http://cnrtl.fr/definition/` pour obtenir des URLs vers le TLF (et autres dictionnaires) accessibles à tous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La (pseudo-)continuation de l'anaphore du début du poème me semble à elle seule justifier ce `puis` là (~ puisque), et ce d'autant plus avec le grand nombre de rimes en -i (et -ir, dans une moindre mesure).

Comment: J'aime beaucoup cette explication, surtout que ce vers est justement celui de la rupture de l'anaphore. Ou plutôt, de son développement (Puisque... Puisque... Je puis...) C'est une façon orale de marquer un changement dans la continuité :-). Merci.

Answer (score 6):

> Je comprends intuitivement que concernant la sonorité, puis est mieux que peux, comme si l'on mettait une sorte de dièse. Et concernant le sens, que puis introduit une forme de retrait par rapport à peux.

Il n'y a rien d'autre à ajouter : c'est un problème d' **intuition**, et donc de *sensibilité*, auditive, certes, mais relationnelle, vis-à-vis de la mémoire de l'aimée et vis-à-vis de sa propre mort.

La *créativité* se tient hors de la mathématique grammaticale et les règlements académiques, même si elle les inclus et les enfreins parfois.

Le fait même que le mot ait raisonné différemment, déclenche une surprise, un arrêt de la lecture automatique, de la connivence que l'on croit avoir avec l'auteur, pour révéler une dimension indéfinissable par essence, et révéler, derrière l'élégance de la formulation, la finesse et la profondeur des émotions.

L'argumentation n'est pas à chercher dans de verbeuses explications, mais dans pourquoi, après plusieurs lectures, ce mot est toujours *vivant* et *présent*.

C'est une exploration intérieure, une interrogation sur l'inconnu où ce mot là, et pas un autre, révèle l'univers manifesté dans le poème. C'est alors une des clefs qui permet de s'y glisser.

Comment: Que la créativité se tienne hors de la mathématique grammaticale ou des règlements ne signifie nullement que l'on ne puisse pas la mesurer, la comprendre, l'exprimer, de façon commune, en plus des insaisissables convictions sensibles personnelles. Pourquoi ce _puis_ là est-il créatif, et que quand je dis _puis-je_ personne ne crie au miracle ?... Mais je reconnais que vous avez raison de mettre en avant l'exploration intérieure, l'interrogation sur l'inconnu, un univers manifesté par le poème. Mais ces choses peuvent être sinon mathématisées, du moins décrites.